# how to add GUI to a hadoop program?

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, mapreduce

I use hadoop to write a Mapreduce program which is able to deploy to ec2 and local  cluster, I am fine to use the command line to run the program, but is there any way to add interface to the hadoop program, so that users just need to click and run the program instead of using command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but I think your  asking if there is an UI for submitting map reduce jobs hadoop?  if so, you should try Hue: http://cloudera.github.com/hue/